# How to open a program in different Xephyr Displays?

Tags: python, linux, python-multiprocessing, xorg, xterm

I have two Xephyr displays created through PyVirtualDisplay, when I try to open `xterm` in both of them it works just fine, but many other programs will open twice on the same display.

So if I do this:

```
DISPLAY=":1001" gedit & DISPLAY=":1005" gedit &
```

it behaves differently than this:

```
DISPLAY=":1001" xterm & DISPLAY=":1005" xterm &
```

Why does it happen though?

Answer (score 0):

To open gedit twice, you have to start a DBus session for each display, as gedit uses DBus to ensure a single instance.